# Windows task scheduler and rights to MSSQL database

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have got a problem with task scheduler.
I scheduled a task that sends email. It's a simply C# console application.
This aplication need to connect to MSSQL server. I am wondering which role, should I grant to this account, to allow only to connect and read tables.
In User Mapping section I choosed:

```
-public
-db_datareader
```

But this roles are not enough.
If I grant the user with role sysadmin (in Server Roles secion), then my task works fine, but I don't want to give this role, because it allows user to do everything with the server.

Which roles I should give to allow to only connect and read tables?
Is there any way to give access only to one particular table?

Comment: `db_datareader` role membership in the needed database is enough to select from tables. If that didn't work for you, what error are you getting? You can be more selective with `GRANT SELECT ON dbo.SomeTable to SomeAccount;`.

Comment: Posting the SQL that is being run would help us greatly here. Also, could SQL Server Agent be a better choice?

Comment: I was missing the EXECUTE permission. I forgot that table isn't read directly by the user but through stored procedure. I granted the execute permission to user and now everything is working fine.
Thank you guys for helping.